# Generalisation of an expression.

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrix-equations, pattern-recognition

I have been solving matrices questions lately and this pattern keeps showing up:

> Given matrix $ P = \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 0\\
> 4 & 1 & 0\\
> 16 & 4 & 1\\
> \end{bmatrix}$ and $I$ be identity matrix of order 3. If $[Q] = [q_{ij}]$ is a matrix such that $P^{50}-Q= I$ then $\frac{q_{31}+q_{32}}{q_{21}} = ?$

While solving I found this pattern for a general matrix of the type:
$$L = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
a & 1 & 0\\
b & a & 1\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
As

$$L^n = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
a×n & 1 & 0\\
K & a×n & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $K = (L_{31})_{{n-1}}+a^2×(n-1) + b$

If I have to figure out $L_{50}$ using this algorithm, I need to find $L_{49}, L_{48}$ and so on which basically defeats the purpose. How do you reiterate the value of $L_{n-1}$ so that I can use directly the value of $b$ to calculate $L_{31}$ of any power of matrix?

Answer (score 4):

By recursion you actually show that
$$P^n=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 4n &
1 & 0 \\ 16n + \frac{(n-1)n}{2}4^2 & 4n &
1\end{bmatrix} ,$$
so you necessarily have
$$Q=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 4n &
0 & 0 \\ 16n + \frac{(n-1)n}{2}4^2 & 4n &
0\end{bmatrix} $$
where $n=50$ (but we will substitute later), so we obtain
$$\frac{q_{31}+q_{32}}{q_{21}}= \frac{16n + \frac{(n-1)n}{2}4^2 + 4n}{4n} = 4 + 2(n-1) + 1 =103.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $L=I+N$ with $N^3=0$. Therefore, $L^n = I+n N + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}N^2$. Since
$$
N^2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
a^2 & 0 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
we get
$$
L^n = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
n a & 1 & 0\\
nb +\frac{n(n-1)}{2}a^2& n a & 1\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$